# Tomcat returns 404 for webapp within Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, tomcat8

i am using Eclipse Mars (4.5.2) and i installed Tomcat 8 as web server, and tried to run a Spring application on it. First, Tomcat management page did not load, but after i 'switched location' and now it shows the application on management site, but if i click on it, it returns 404. If i manually copy the war file, it runs, also if i run with

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
            <path>/dcollect</path>
                <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                <server>TomcatServer</server>
            <warFile>${project.build.directory}/dcollect.war</warFile>
                <username>admin</username>
                <password>admin</password>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

whitin maven, it also works just fine.

But if i run with 'Run on server', it shows the app on the list, but returns 404:
[image]

Comment: Can you open tomcat configuration under servers tab and check if your war project in there?

Comment: Yes it is there. Also /SpringMVC is there as path, but still 404. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out eclipse didn't export maven dependencies deploying the proyect. While packaging first to WAR it did include that. I had to do "proyect properties -> deployment assembly -> add java build path entries -> maven dependencies".

I can not explain why eclipse did not include that automatically, while importing other maven proyects from github for example it does.

[image]